# TestFlight crash reporting not working in rubymotion

Tags: ios, rubymotion, testflight

Having read the TestFlight SDK docs I assumed that crash reporting should happen automatically, however this doesn't seem to be the case with my rubymotion app.

In the Rakefile I have included the following configuration:

```
app.testflight.sdk        = 'vendor/TestFlight'
app.testflight.api_token  = '...'
app.testflight.team_token = '...'
```

I can successfully upload builds with `rake testflight notes='...'` but no crash reports reach TestFlight neither from simulator nor from device.

Are there any other configuration options in the app or on the tf account I need to set?

Answer (score 1):

In your AppDelegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method you need to add the following line:

```
TestFlight.takeOff(application_token)
```

You can view further TestFlight documentation here: https://testflightapp.com/sdk/ios/doc/2.0.0/

Comment: Under rybymotion the motion testflight gem does that automatically.

Comment: So it does. Did you add your app token to your Rakefile?